# Is it possible to deep link for the android fragment

Tags: android

How do apply deep linking of a fragment page while app invitation. It is easy to handle deep linking for the activity class, How can I manage for the android fragment deep linking ?

Comment: you can't on fragment but which is your fragment parent add Deep_linking to that Fragment Activity or Activity.

Comment: yes possible by calling fragments inside the activity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273754/deeplink-into-another-fragment-android

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible for you to put the deep link to the fragment but, You can sent the deep link into your main activity then, your can filter that string from the deep link belongs to fragment and you can trigger the fragment from that string.