# Deeplink into another fragment [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, deep-linking, applinks

The structure of activity and fragment is like :

Using NavigationDrawer.

MainActivity has a container for Fragment, in one container there should be have many fragment. After launch the app, default of fragment is fragment A.

Implement deeplink into MainActivity with Fragment B, how I can change the fragment from Fragment A(default) into Fragment B (destination).

Any help will helpfull :)
Thanks

i.e
**class handle Applink**

```
    override fun onInitView() {
    handleIntent()
  }

  private fun handleIntent() {
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to handle app links.
    val intent = intent
    val appLinkAction = intent.action
    val appLinkData = intent.data
    if (appLinkData != null) {
      handleAppLinkIntent(appLinkData)
    } else {
      handleActivityIntent(intent)
    }
  }

  protected abstract fun handleActivityIntent(intent: Intent)

  protected abstract fun handleAppLinkIntent(appLinkData: Uri)
```

**impl function**

```
    @Override
  protected void handleActivityIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
      switch (this.paramMainMenu) {
        case Constants.ZERO:
          this.goToProductList();
          break;
        case Constants.ONE:
          this.goToFragmentA();
          break;
        case Constants.TWO:
          this.goToFragmentB();
          break;
        case Constants.THREE:
          this.goToFragmentC();
          break;
      }
    }
  }

@Override
  protected void handleAppLinkIntent(Uri appLinkData) {
    if(appLinkData.getQueryParameterNames().isEmpty()){
      String path = appLinkData.getPath();
      switch (path) {
        case "/kfc/food/price/outofstock":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.ONE;
          break;
        case "/food/price/qty":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.THREE;
          break;
        case "/price/unbuyable":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.TWO;
          break;
        case "/price":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.ZERO;
          break;
        case "/food/price":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.ZERO;
          break;
        case "/a/food/item":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.ZERO;
          break;
        case "/":
          this.paramMainMenu = Constants.ZERO;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `NavigationDrawer`, `BottomNavigation` or `ViewPager`.

Comment: using NavigationDrawer @ZwalPyaeKyaw

Comment: You can use `FragmentManager()` to switch between `Fragment`s.

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(). 
              replace(R.id.flContainer, new DemoFragment(), "SOMETAG").
              commit();
          // Now later we can lookup the fragment by tag
          DemoFragment fragmentDemo = (DemoFragment) 
              getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SOMETAG");` like this. Here's the [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments) to tutorial.

Comment: I've use that, the function is the same with clickListener on NavigationDrawer menu. now the problem is when I call the function of switch fragment into handleIntent on Applink, there is no effect. I'm always goto fragment A.

Comment: Can you add the code to Question?

Answer (score 1):

your URL should contains some key-values to determine the the fragment to be open
let us take a example :
Fragment-A is design to show list of offers
Fragment-B is design to show list of product

your URL contains a key that should show the "product".

you can segregate the fragment based on the key-value of deeplink

Example

your url is

> "https://xyzcompany.com/myapp?open=products"
>
> insinde MainActivity.class  onCreate()

```
String key;
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    if (appLinkData != null) {
        key = appLinkData.getQueryParameter("open");
    }

 if(key == products){
       //launch Fragment-B
    } else {
      //launch Fraagment-A
 }
```

Comment: I'm success when there is a key, I can't handle when there is no key :(

Comment: does the deeplink is only for Fragment-B or sometime it is applicable for fragment-A also ?

Comment: impl to many fragment. therefore I make handleAppLink become a class

Answer (score 0):

Android added Navigation Components in Android Jetpack libraries to handle complex navigation scenarios in the application.

You can create destination(Fragments etc.) and link them via actions to navigate from one destination to another destination. You can associate deep links with fragments using navigation components. This should be able solve you problem.

Check the following links for more details:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link